# Library build with netcoreapp3.1 throws errors on GitHub actions trying to run tests on multiple frameworks

Tags: c#, .net-core, github-actions, xunit.net

I'm trying to contribute to a great project (https://github.com/billbogaiv/hybrid-model-binding) - I want to update the target framework and set up tests.
My fork: https://github.com/Misiu/hybrid-model-binding/tree/tests
I've updated the project from `netstandard2.1` to `netcoreapp3.1` and everything works fine.
So now I have 3 projects in the solution:

- HybridModelBinding - main library project
- AspNetCoreWebApplication - project with samples
- HybridModelBinding.UnitTests - project that will contain unit tests

I'd like my tests to run on multiple dotnet versions, so I've added this workflow:

```
name: .NET Core
# Trigger event on a push or pull request
on: [push, pull_request]

# Jobs that run in parallel
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        dotnet-version: [ '3.1.x','5.0.x', '6.0.x' ]
    # Steps that run sequentially
    steps:
    
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
    - name: Setup .NET Core SDK ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1.7.2
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
        
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
      
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
      
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-restore --verbosity normal
```

So in theory everything should be built and run on 3 runtimes.
The first build works fine (on 3.1.x), but the second and third throw  errors:

> Test run for
> /home/runner/work/hybrid-model-binding/hybrid-model-binding/tests/HybridModelBinding.UnitTests/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/HybridModelBinding.UnitTests.dll
> (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1) Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line
> Tool Version 16.11.0 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights
> reserved.
>
> Starting test execution, please wait... A total of 1 test files
> matched the specified pattern. Testhost process exited with error: It
> was not possible to find any compatible framework version The
> framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found.
>
> - The following frameworks were found:
>   5.0.14 at [/home/runner/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App] You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework
>   and/or SDK. The specified framework can be found at:
> - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=3.1.0&arch=x64&rid=ubuntu.20.04-x64
>   . Please check the diagnostic logs for more information.
>
> Test Run Aborted.
> 3>Done Building Project "/home/runner/work/hybrid-model-binding/hybrid-model-binding/tests/HybridModelBinding.UnitTests/HybridModelBinding.UnitTests.csproj"
> (VSTest target(s)) -- FAILED.
> 1>Done Building Project "/home/runner/work/hybrid-model-binding/hybrid-model-binding/HybridModelBinding.sln"
> (VSTest target(s)) -- FAILED.
>
> Build FAILED.

Build summary: https://github.com/Misiu/hybrid-model-binding/runs/5392702331?check_suite_focus=true

I can compile projects locally and run the tests, but I'd like to run them on GitHub, so in the future, we can add more tests and develop the library easier.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the Target framework monikers (TFMs) via `include` under the matrix and specify the framework for `dotnet test` by adding the argument `-f=${{ matrix.tfm }}`.

```
name: .NET Core
# Trigger event on a push or pull request
on: [push, pull_request]

# Jobs that run in parallel
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        include:
        - dotnet-version: '3.1.x'
          tfm: 'netcoreapp3.1'
        - dotnet-version: '5.0.x'
          tfm: 'net5.0'
        - dotnet-version: '6.0.x'
          tfm: 'net6.0'
    # Steps that run sequentially
    steps:
    
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
    - name: Setup .NET Core SDK ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1.7.2
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
        
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: dotnet restore -p:TargetFramework=${{ matrix.tfm }}
      
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
      
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-restore --verbosity normal -f=${{ matrix.tfm }}
```

Sources

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#supported-target-frameworks
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test#options
- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#using-environment-variables-in-a-matrix

Comment: thank you for a quick answer, however, I get the following error: https://github.com/Misiu/hybrid-model-binding/runs/5403451494?check_suite_focus=true.  All my projects target `netcoreapp3.1`

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using [multi targeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/multiple-target-frameworks-project-file)? You can't run a .NET Core 3.1 app on .NET 5.

Comment: Should I use multi-targeting on my test project only? Or on the library and the test project? This is my first time trying to set up tests on multiple framework versions.

Comment: I would keep the library at .NET Standard 2.1 (avoids having multiple binaries and keeps the library as generic as possible) and use multi targeting for the examples project and the test project.

Comment: I've done the suggested changes (I target .NET Standard 2.1) and I'm only building a single project, but now I get this error: https://github.com/Misiu/hybrid-model-binding/runs/5406406441?check_suite_focus=true (error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 6.0.  Either target .NET 5.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 6.0. [/home/runner/work/hybrid-model-binding/hybrid-model-binding/tests/HybridModelBinding.UnitTests/HybridModelBinding.UnitTests.csproj])

Comment: See my edit, use `dotnet restore -p:TargetFramework=${{ matrix.tfm }}`

Comment: thank you for your patience, but sadly I still have had no success. My workflow file: https://github.com/Misiu/hybrid-model-binding/blob/tests/.github/workflows/tests.yml. Now for netcoreapp3.1 it failed on build, on .net5 and .net6 it failed on installing dependencies

Comment: Try `dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore -f=${{ matrix.tfm }}` and remove the separate `dotnet restore`.
If this doesn't work you can try switching the library to multi targeting, too.

Comment: Still no success :/ https://github.com/Misiu/hybrid-model-binding/runs/5409018693?check_suite_focus=true

Comment: `dotnet build --configuration Release -f=${{ matrix.tfm }}` (without  `--no-restore`). Plan is to restore and build in one step.

Comment: Now all builds fail :/ https://github.com/Misiu/hybrid-model-binding/actions/runs/1930062361